# Am i missing something on templates on django

Tags: python, django, web

This is my code on html file on a django project. I am using this code on this function

```
def home(request):
    context = {
        'post': posts
    }
    return render(request,'blog/home.html',context
```

It does not display anything when I see page source it's just bacis html code head and body empty

````
<html>
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
    {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
        <p>By {{post.author}} on {{post.date_posted}}</p>
        <p>{{post.content}}</p>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Whats your question ?

Comment: what kind of problem are you facing?

Comment: i editited this post my page shows nothing

Comment: You are setting the posts to the context as the name `post` but accessing it as `posts` so in your template you might face the error.

Comment: so i should change the name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a typo. You need to change the context in your view from:

```
context = { 'post': posts }
```

to

```
 context = { 'posts': posts } 
             ^^^^^^^
```